# How to extract the multiplied numbers from the given string?

Tags: excel, regex, vba, text-extraction

I need to  extract the multiplied numbers from the given strings.
The multiplication parameter (as a string) is either `"x"` or `"*"` (asterisk sign).
The numbers itself may contain (or not) the inch sign (double quotes ").
There is a white space may be found (or not) between multiplication parameter and numbers itself.
I have tried the below function, But it extracts all numbers from string and combine them.
also **case sensitivity is not importan**t as I am always using `Option Compare Text` on all my macros.

| Current String | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| XX 2" * 3" RRR | 2x3 |
| BBB 2"*3" HHH | 2x3 |
| MMMM 2*3*5 FF EE | 2x3x5 |
| RTE 2*3 EE XX | 2x3 |
| AAA 4.5 x 5'' ERT EE | 4.5x5 |
| XX 4''x5'' XX XX | 4x5 |
| WWW 4''x 3.5 WWW | 4x3.5 |
| EEE 4*5 NN | 4x5 |

```
Function GetNumeric(CellRef As String)
    Dim StringLength As Long, i As Long, Result As Variant
    StringLength = Len(CellRef)
    For i = 1 To StringLength
      If IsNumeric(Mid(CellRef, i, 1)) Then
         Result = Result & Mid(CellRef, i, 1)
      End If
    Next i
    GetNumeric = Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is based on your previous questions and the answers given to those. It assumes that you would also have different looking sample data like `3 inch * 5 in` for example. You could again create your own UDF based on a regular expression. For this case I created an 'RegexExtract' and 'RegexReplace' function:

```
Public Function RegexExtract(str As String, pat As String, Optional gFlag As Boolean = False, Optional pos As Integer = 0, Optional cse As Boolean = True) As String

Static RE As Object: If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = pat
RE.Global = gFlag
RE.IgnoreCase = cse

If RE.Test(str) Then
    RegexExtract = RE.Execute(str)(pos)
Else
    RegexExtract = vbNullString
End If

End Function

Public Function RegexReplace(str As String, pat As String, rep As String, Optional gFlag As Boolean = True, Optional cse As Boolean = True) As String

Static RE As Object: If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = pat
RE.Global = gFlag
RE.IgnoreCase = cse
RegexReplace = RE.Replace(str, rep)

End Function
```

I called the functions using:

```
=RegexReplace(RegexExtract(A2,"\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|""|in(?:ch)?\b)?(?:\s*[*x]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|""|in(?:ch)?\b)?)*\s*[*x]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?"),"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[^\d.]+","$1x")
```

This results in:

[image]

---

**RegexExtract:**

This part would look at your input and extract a substring based on this pattern:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|"|in(?:ch)?\b)?(?:\s*[*x]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|"|in(?:ch)?\b)?)*\s*[*x]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AlNL9x/1)

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|"|in(?:ch)?\b)?` - Match digits with optional decimals *and* optional trailing inch demarcation;
- `(?:` - Open a non-capture group;

  - `\s*[*x]\s*` - Match an asterisk or literal 'x' between 0+ whitespace chars;
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|"|in(?:ch)?\b)?` - Match the same pattern as in the 1st bullit;
  - `)*` - Close the non-capture group and match it 0+ times.

---

**RegexReplace:**

This part would look at your input and replace a substring based on this pattern:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[^\d.]+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqhmEC/1)

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - A 1st capture group to match digits with optional decimals;
- `[^\d.]+` - 1+ (Greedy) characters other than digit or dot.

Replace with a backreference to this 1st group:

```
$1x
```

**Note:** The link will show a different pattern to exclude newline chars from the samples.

Comment: If this doesn't cover it I don't know what will :-)

Comment: It works perfectly and exactly as I need  , I will follow your answers to learn more about `Regex` and VBA

Comment: @Waleed, yet there was one small adjustment I had to make =). Glad you are helped.

Comment: Yes you are correct , I have mixed between old & new pattern while I made tests (I am sorry)

Comment: Please, could you adapt a little, Because on my real dataset it fails with this string `2"x3"x4` , although it works correctly with `2"x3x4` and even `2"x3x4x5` , I tried hardly to change (pattern of inch demarcation) but it did not work.

Comment: @Waleed, see updated pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple replace:

```
Function GetNumeric(CellRef As String) As String
    GetNumeric = Replace(CellRef, " ", "")
    GetNumeric = Replace(GetNumeric, """", "")
    GetNumeric = Replace(GetNumeric, "'", "")
    GetNumeric = Replace(GetNumeric, "*", "x")
End Function
```

Comment: It also has two single quotes instead of double quote in example.

Comment: @markalex Thanks for the hint, didn't notice that. But the fix is easy... - code updated

Comment: Sorry, yes it works with given example, But when I tried on my real dataset I found that it also extract all the other strings on the cell !

Comment: I don't know your real dataset...

Comment: you are correct, I have updated my samples to be more accurate

Comment: Now the function needs to be more sophisticated. Are all characters Uppercase as in your example data? Is the `x` between the numbers always lowercase?

Comment: it can be a mix of Uppercase & lowercase , anyhow I am always using `Option Compare Text` on all my macros.

Comment: But that means you could have an "x" as Text and not as multiply character. Which means also that you cannot simply remove all Upper characters. Which means that you first need to find the beginning and ending of your numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This would work, however, `Option Compare Text` is going to cause problems if you have uppercase `X`s in your sample data..

```
Function GetNumeric(CellRef As String)
    Dim include As String, i As Long
    include = "0123456789.x*"
    For i = 1 To Len(CellRef)
        If InStr(1, include, Mid(CellRef, i, 1)) <> 0 Then GetNumeric = GetNumeric & Mid(CellRef, i, 1)
    Next
    GetNumeric = Replace(GetNumeric, "*", "x")
End Function
```

If you need a function that works with `Option Compare Text`, you can use:

```
Function GetNumeric2(CellRef As String)
    Dim include As String, i As Long, j As Long
    include = "0123456789.x*"
    For i = 1 To Len(CellRef)
        For j = 1 To Len(include)
            If Asc(Mid(CellRef, i, 1)) = Asc(Mid(include, j, 1)) Then GetNumeric2 = GetNumeric2 & Mid(CellRef, i, 1)
        Next
    Next
    GetNumeric2 = Replace(GetNumeric2, "*", "x")
End Function
```

Finally, a version that should allow for `2X2`:

```
Function GetNumeric3(CellRef As String)
    Dim include As String, i As Long
    include = "0123456789.x*"
    For i = 1 To Len(CellRef)
        If InStr(1, include, Mid(CellRef, i, 1)) <> 0 Then GetNumeric3 = GetNumeric3 & Mid(CellRef, i, 1)
    Next
    GetNumeric3 = Replace(GetNumeric3, "*", "x")
    For i = 1 To Len(GetNumeric3)
        If Left(GetNumeric3, 1) = "x" Then GetNumeric3 = Mid(GetNumeric3, 2)
        If Right(GetNumeric3, 1) = "x" Then GetNumeric3 = Left(GetNumeric3, Len(GetNumeric3) - 1)
    Next
    GetNumeric3 = LCase(GetNumeric3)
End Function
```

Thanks to FunThomas for the assist.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried your second code, But I found if x is found as uppercase then the numbers are combined together.

Comment: I guess that wasn't in your sample inputs? Do you mean something like `2X2` -> `22`?

Comment: yes exactly  `2X2` -> `22`

Comment: remove leading and trailing "x" after all the other work.

Comment: now it works with my provided samples as it should, up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function together with a lookup table:

```
=LET(colLookup,VSTACK(tblLookup,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65))),
step1, REDUCE([@[Current String]],colLookup,
     LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,""))),
SUBSTITUTE(step1,"x","*"))
```

`CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)` creates a list from A to Z

[image]

--- Update: VBA solution

```vb
Public Function replaceExt(t As String) As String

Dim charToReplace As Variant
charToReplace = Array("""", "'", " ")

Dim i As Long
'replace defined characters
For i = 0 To UBound(charToReplace)
    t = Replace(t, charToReplace(i), "")
Next

'now replace all upper charachters ASCII 65 to 90
For i = 65 To 90
    t = Replace(t, Chr(i), "")
Next

'Finally replace lower case x by *
t = Replace(t, "x", "*")
replaceExt = t
End Function
```

Comment: it dose not work with office 2016 .

Comment: Sorry - that's right

Comment: I updated the answer with a vba solution - it will replace the A to Z as well

Comment: Please,  Did you tried the vba solution with my updated samples , because I tried and it gives wrong result ?

Comment: also case sensitivity is not important as I am always using `Option Compare Text` on all my macros

Comment: You are right: with `Option Compare Text` and lower case characters it doesn't work. You should describe your requirements in your question better ... the replacement is case sensitive due the the lower case x that should be replaced by *

Comment: You could use a regular expression to replace the lower case x between two figures/blanks by e.g. $ - then do the replacements - and finally replace the $ by x