# Add double quotations " for the multiplied numbers

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I need to add double quotations `"` for the multiplied numbers for the given strings.
The multiplication operator (as a string) is either "`x`" , "`X`" or "`*`".
I have used the below function to extract the multiplied numbers, originated question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002646/how-to-extract-the-multiplied-numbers-from-the-given-string).

| Current String | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| string 2 x 3 string | string 2"x3" string |
| string 2X3" string | string 2"X3" string |
| string 2*3*5 string | string 2"*3"*5" string |
| string 2"*3 string | string 2"*3" string |
| string 4.5 x 5 string | string 4.5"x5" string |
| string 4"x5" string | string 4"x5" string |
| string 4x 3.5" string | string 4"x3.5" string |

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

    Function RegexExtractt(str, Optional pos As Integer = 0) As String
    
        Static re As Object
        If re Is Nothing Then Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        
        re.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|""|in(?:ch)?\b)?(?:\s*[*x]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:''|""|in(?:ch)?\b)?)*\s*[*x]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
        re.Global = False
        re.IgnoreCase = True
        
        If re.test(str) Then
            RegexExtractt = re.Execute(str)(pos)
        Else
            RegexExtractt = vbNullString
        End If
    
    End Function
```

Comment: Nice, but what's your question?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `(\d)"?\s*([xX*])\s*(\d+(?:\s*\.\d+)?)"?` and replace with the 3 capture groups `$1"$2$3"` then after the replacements, replace the `""` in this `string 2"*3""*5" string`  with a single `"` See https://regex101.com/r/jpayJV/1

Comment: @The fourth bird , because the pattern includes `"` so it caused a syntax error on vba , I have replaced all of it by `Chr(34)` and VBA code exactly became `re.Pattern = "(\d)" & Chr(34) & "?\s*([xX*])\s*(\d+(?:\s*\.\d+)?)" & Chr(34) & "?"`  and `RegexExtractt = re.Replace(str, "$1" & Chr(34) & "$2$3")`  , Anyhow it dose not work and double quotation are only add to the first number.

Comment: @Waleed I see, and if you use 2 capture groups? https://regex101.com/r/cpm9ap/1

Comment: @The fourth bird , yes all works,except `""` in this string `2"*3""*5"` , But I can easily replace it by Substitute, you can post as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with doing a second replace for `""` to `"` after obtaining for example this result `string 2"*3""*5" string`  you could first do:

```
"?\s*([xX*])\s*(\d+(?:\s*\.\d+)?)"?
```

The pattern matches

- `"?\s*` Match an optional `"` and optional whitespace chars
- `([xX*])` Capture one of `x` `X` `*` in **group 1**
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(\d+(?:\s*\.\d+)?)` Capture 1+ digits with an optional decimal part in **group 2**
- `"?` Optionally match `"`

In the first replacement use the 2 capture groups between double quotes `"$1$2"`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXuRnj/1).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76002646/9758194) questions, this is my two cents:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:''|"|in(?:ch)?\b)?(?:\s*([*x])\s*(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?
```

Replace with:

```
$1"$2
```

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/C4XKKf/1) online demo.

---

Invoke this through:

```
=RegexReplace(A1,"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:''|""|in(?:ch)?\b)?(?:\s*([*x])\s*(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?","$1""$2")
```

**Note:** This is based on the replace-function as per your linked previous question, which is case-insensitive per design.

Also, maybe your sample data is a bit too simplified. I can't imagine this to be working on actual data which may contain digits in other places you want to leave untouched.

Comment: Yes, I have found your code add double quotes for all other numbers on the cell, I am sad   it is not working, because it was will be a comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following VBA function, which covers all cases of the example:
(with a caveat: Things are not always as they seem... there is the unprintable character with code 160, it looks like a space -code 32- but it's not.)

```
'The code don't work if use Option Compare Text because of x and X
Public Function doTheJob(s As String) As String
   Const qt = """", m0 = " ", m1 = "x", m2 = "X", m3 = "*"
   Dim t As String, pa As Integer, pz As Integer
   t = Replace(s, m0, " ")
   pa = InStr(1, t, " ")
   pz = InStrRev(t, " ")
   doTheJob = Left(t, pa) & Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Trim(Mid(t, pa + 1, pz - pa)), qt, "") _
                  , " ", ""), m1, qt & m1), m2, qt & m2), m3, qt & m3) & qt & Mid(t, pz)
End Function
 

'The code below works WITH or WITHOUT Option Compare Text
Public Function doTheJob(s As String) As String
   Const qt = """", m0 = " ", m1 = "x", m2 = "X", m3 = "*"
   Dim t As String, pa As Integer, pz As Integer
   t = Replace(s, m0, " ")
   pa = InStr(1, t, " ")
   pz = InStrRev(t, " ")
   t = Replace(Replace(Trim(Mid(t, pa + 1, pz - pa)), qt, ""), " ", "")
   If InStr(1, t, m3) Then
      t = Replace(t, m3, qt & m3)
   Else
      If InStr(1, t, m1) Then
         t = Replace(t, m1, qt & m1)
      Else
         t = Replace(t, m2, qt & m2)
      End If
   End If
   doTheJob = Left(s, pa) & t & qt & Mid(s, pz)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I am always use `Option Compare Text` (as you see on my code) , I tried your code and it add two double quotation  `""` for some numbers. If I used your answer without (Option Compare Text) then it works correctly.